# Ansible playbook - what is a play?

Tags: ansible

I've just started learning Ansible and have a question about what defines a "play". If I'm looking at a temple, my understanding is a play typically starts with the following:

```
-
  name: xxx
  hosts: yyy
```

I've read that the **name**: keyword is not required (but highly recommend). So with that being the case, how can I tell where one play begins and where the next one starts? What keywords delimit/demarc a single play when there are multiple plays in a playbook?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Plays`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-plays):

> A [playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-playbooks) is a list of plays. **A play is minimally a mapping between a
>   set of [hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-host) selected by a host specifier (usually chosen by [groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-group)
>   but sometimes by hostname globs) and the [tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-tasks) which run on those
>   hosts to define the role that those systems will perform.** There can be
>   one or many plays in a playbook.

Play refers to the set (one or more) of actions (tasks) you want to execute on a set (one of more) of hosts.

As for the syntax of a Play, you can find examples for single and multiple play playbook [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for that link franklinsjo.  That cleared things up. In summary, here's the takeaway:

```
A play consists of:

- name: (optional, but recommended)
  hosts:
  tasks:
```

So, as you're looking through a playbook, anytime you come to the keywords hosts: and tasks:, that indicates the start of a play (along with the optional name: keyword).

Thanks,

Andy