# Ansible special tag 'never' is not working with import_playbook and --tags

Tags: ansible

The special tag 'never' is not applied in my second use case. I can't find out in the Ansible document if this is normal behavior, or if it is a bug.

playbook-parent.yml

```yaml
- name: parent playbook
  import_playbook: playbook-child.yml
  tags:
    - toto
```

playbook-child.yml

```yaml
- hosts: local
  roles:
    - role: test
      tags:
        - never
```

roles/test/tasks/main.yml

```yaml
- name: hello word
  copy:
    content: hello world
    dest: testfile.txt
```

**Test Case 1: Tag never is applied with the command below ==> OK :)**

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook-parent.yml

PLAY [local] **********************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************
ok: [127.0.0.]

PLAY RECAP ************************************
...
```

**Test Case 2: Tag 'never' is not applied with the command below ==> Normal? Bug?**

```sh
ansible-playbook playbook-parent.yml --tags toto

PLAY [local] **********************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************
ok: [127.0.0.]

TASK [test: help word] ************************
changed: [127.0.0.]

PLAY RECAP ************************************
...
```

Comment: The naming of the playbooks suggests that the *child* playbook is inheriting from the *parent* playbook. Which is actually not. The structure is flat. This is a playbook with one play only.  See [Ansible playbook - what is a play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61080848/ansible-playbook-what-is-a-play). *playbook-child.yml* is a **play** inside the **playbook** *playbook-parent.yml*.

Comment: Oh thanks for bringing out this point. I realised the way i named my playbooks was not good at all with parent and child in it. Now i have a better understanding with all the comments I got here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Q: **"*The special tag 'never' is not applied in my second use case, I can't find out in the Ansible document if this is normal behavior.*"**

A: Quoting from [Special tags: always and never](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags-always-and-never)

> If you assign the never tag to a task or play, Ansible will skip that task
> or play unless you specifically request it (--tags never).

Given the role

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: ansible_run_tags
```

The play

```yaml
shell> cat playbook-child.yml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
  - role: test
    tags:
      - never
```

works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook-child.yml -t never
```

displays the debug message

```yaml
TASK [test : debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_run_tags:
  - never
```

and the play without the tag does nothing

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook-child.yml
```

---

The next playbook applies the tag *toto* to all tasks in the playbook *playbook-child.yml*

```yaml
shell> cat playbook-parent.yml
- name: parent playbook
  import_playbook: playbook-child.yml
  tags:
    - toto
```

As expected, without any tag the play does nothing

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook-parent.yml
```

But if any of the tags *toto* or *never* or both are applied the play displays the debug message

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook-parent.yml -t toto

TASK [test : debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_run_tags:
  - toto
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook-parent.yml -t never

TASK [test : debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_run_tags:
  - never
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook-parent.yml -t never,toto

TASK [test : debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_run_tags:
  - never
  - toto
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your time and explanation! Now I have a better idea that the ansible applies tag inheritance to the tasks in the imported playbook. As I have tag toto in my parent playbook, all the tasks in the child playbook inherits this tag. 
So it is a normal behavior! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be misunderstanding the function of the `never` tag. As [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags-always-and-never) says:

> If you assign the never tag to a task or play, Ansible will skip that task or play unless you specifically request it

You have specifically requested that play to run by passing `--tags toto`, so it ran. Your example is overly complex; you can demonstrate the behaviour clearly in a single playbook.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: task 1
      tags:
        - never

    - debug:
        msg: task 2
      tags:
        - never
        - foo

    - debug:
        msg: task 3
      tags:
        - foo

    - debug:
        msg: task 4
```

`ansible-playbook test.yml`:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 3"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 4"
}
```

`ansible-playbook test.yml --tags foo`:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 2"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 3"
}
```

`ansible-playbooks --tags foo --skip-tags never`:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. 
The tag never works perfectly with a single playbook. What I wanted to point out is the never tag is no more working the same way when we use the import_playbook and --tags at the same time.

Comment: @OceaniaWater It *is* working the same way. You have ```import_playbook: playbook-child.yml
  tags:
    - toto
``` and are passing `--tags toto`, so playbook-child.yml runs.

Comment: Thanks. With the cmd import_playbook: playbook-child.yml and --tags toto.
the task was executed, I got a testfile.txt created. the tag never is not applied.

Comment: Yes, it is applied. The task runs because it has the tag `toto`, and you told Ansible to run tasks with the tag `toto`. This is the expected behaviour. You can verify that it is applied by adding `--skip-tags never` to your command.

Comment: Yes, because you added the tag `toto` to all of the tasks in the playbook, and then requested that tag.

Comment: Really thanks for your time.
Just continue with your example playbook test.yml with my playbook-parent.yml that includes your test playbook by using include_playbook and has its own tags : toto. I got different results with these two commands. Is it normal for you?    
`ansible-playbook playbook-parent.yml --tags toto`
and
`ansible-playbook playbook-parent.yml --tags foo`

Comment: In another word, with your test.yml playbook example, if i call it with a parent playbook with --tags toto, the task 1 of test.yml is executed. While task 1 is not executed in any of your three use cases of your examples.

Comment: Yes, because you added the tag toto to all of the tasks in the playbook, and then requested that tag.

Comment: Oh I see, you meant when I declare toto in the parent’s tag, the child inherits the tag toto too and when I run for tag toto, the whole playbook of child will be executed?